# How to error proof my javascript item list from entering the same item or no item

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to error proof JavaScript from item list by entering the same item or no item. Please help me guys of been researching for days StackOverFlow is my last hope. Any Help will be appreciated.`Thanks guys

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('SportController', function($scope) {
 
 $scope.newItem;
 
 //List Sport
 $scope.sports = ['Football', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 'Soccer'];
 
 
 //Remove Sport
 $scope.addItem = function(){
         
  
  $scope.sports.push($scope.newItem);
  $scope.newItem = '';
  
 }
 
 
 //Remove Sport
 $scope.removeItem = function(item){
  var idx = $scope.sports.indexOf(item);
  $scope.sports.splice(idx,1);
  
 }
 
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
 <div ng-controller='SportController'>
 <h1>Sport List</h1>
 
 <div>
  <form ng-submit="addItem()">
   <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="newItem" placeholder"Add Sport"/>
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
         </form>
     </div>
     <p> {{ newItem }}</p>
     <div>
      <h4>Sports {{ sports.length }}</h4>  
         <table>
             <tr ng-repeat="spor in sports">
                 <td>{{spor}}</td> 
                 <td>
                     <button ng-click="removeItem(spor)">&times;</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </table>
       </div>
    <!--End of div--->                    


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Error-proof Code = Two-horned Unicorn

Comment: I dont understand your joke.

Answer (score 0):

Block the UI from being able to submit.

Or use a simple if check...

```
$scope.addItem = function(item){

    //blank item
    if(!item) return; //or display an alert

    //item already exists
    if($scope.sports.indexOf(item) > -1) return; //or display a different alert

    $scope.sports.push(item);
    $scope.newItem = null;

}
```

Comment: I still cant figure it out. please write code fully with placements. thanks

Comment: Anyone else out there that can shine a better light?